# Maximum and Minimum electron energy

Tags: radiation, half-life

I am trying to find the maximum and minimum electron energy for the calculation of the beta spectrum. I understood the minimum energy of the electron is the Q value. What is the maximum energy of the electron in any beta decay?

Comment: Why is the Q value the minimum energy? That is all the energy released in the decay. There is no more...

Comment: The Q value of the energy is 4450 KeV, I am trying to find the range of electron energies with 1KeV binning, and I have 19 endpoints energies.

Comment: The electron
energy should be defined with a arbitrarily chosen binwidth (e.g. 1 keV)
up to the endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the large mass of the recoiling nucleus in $\beta$-decay, it is safe to assume that the energy released in the decay, $Q$, is split between the electron and neutrino which result from it. This automatically gives you an upper bound for the electron energy - even if the neutrino does not recoil at all, the total available energy for the electron is still $Q$, with the value depending on the difference of the masses of the initial and final nucleus. You can find an equation for the electron energy distribution e.g. on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_decay#Beta_emission_spectrum). From the same webpage you can see the energy spectrum of the electron in $^{210}$Bi, with $E_{max}=1.16$ MeV.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I want to calculate a beta spectra and I just know the endpoints, branching ratios and the yield. I need the electron energies. Is there any way to find the range for electron energies. My Q value is 4450 KeV

Comment: I am not sure I follow what you are asking for. I suggest you modify your initial question to include what you are given and what you need to find. The energy of the electron can range between 0 and $E_{max}$, with the value of $E_{max}(Q)$ and the shape of the distribution dependant on the decay.